# Kotlin combine two callbackflows depending from each other

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have data class, `MySection`, which has the ID in it. I have another data class  `MyArticle` whdoesn'ton't care about its content

To get the Section,

```
private fun getSectionFlow(): Flow<List<MySection>> =
        callbackFlow {
        
              val listCallBackFlow = object : SectionCallback<List<MySection>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(sections: List<MySection>) {
                       trySend(sections)
                    }
                    override fun onError(errorResponse: ErrorResponse) {
                        close(Exception(errorResponse.reason))
                    }
               }

              provider.getSections(
                    listCallBackFlow
              )

              awaitClose() 
         }
```

And for Article,

```
private fun getArticleFlow(id: Long): Flow<List<MyArticle>> =
        callbackFlow {
        
              val listCallBackFlow = object : ArticleCallback<List<MyArticle>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(sections: List<MyArticle>) {
                       trySend(sections)
                    }
                    override fun onError(errorResponse: ErrorResponse) {
                        close(Exception(errorResponse.reason))
                    }
               }

              provider.getArticle(
                    id, // to get the article list it needs section id
                    listCallBackFlow
              )

              awaitClose() 
         }
```

And finally, all values need to bind in `List<MySectionWithArticle>`

```
data class MySectionWithArticle (
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    var myArticlesList: List<MyArticle> = emptyList()
)
```

So the inputs to `getArticleFlow(id)` should be the IDs of the values from `getSectionFlow()`

So the main question is how can I combine two callbackflow functions in such a way it gives me combine values `MySection` ,`List<MyArticle>` to `MySectionWithArticle`?

So for `List<MySection>`, each `MySection` need to call `getArticleFlow(id)` function and then `List<MyArticle>` combine with  `MySectionWithArticle` data class

How can I achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use flows instead of suspend functions? It seems you return single values from both functions, so flows are not really needed here. It would be easier to implement this with suspend functions.

Comment: Yes I am converting all callback methods into flows and using as everywhere @broot

Comment: Are those one-shot callbacks? or are the callbacks called repeatedly? If one-shot, you should convert them to suspend functions, not flows, as broot said. Check [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) which is meant for that

Comment: No @Joffrey those are not one-shot functions. It's like repeatedly. Example, we got 5 section from getSection and then need to call 5 times  getArticle function and them merge into one list.

Comment: Yes, but you get list of sections in `onSuccess()`, so it seems like `onSuccess()` is only invoked once, with all 5 sections. If this is the case then I suggest to use suspend functions.

Comment: @Joffrey Why I used flow because flow has capabilities like flatMapConcat with a combine that the reason I choose callbackflow. If you have idea like how we can achieve with suspendcancellablecoroutine then please let me know how can I achieve it?

Comment: correct @broot it is possible with suspend function as well but after that I need to call article function 5 times right so, how I achieve with 5 times values in return and how can I store it and finally merge it. that what my main question. I don't mind to use suspend function .

Comment: `flatMapConcat()` and similar functions are required, because flows are **harder** to handle, so they need special utils. If these would be suspend functions returning just lists, then combining them would be as simple as: `getSections().map { MySectionWithArticle(it, getArticles(it.id) }`. This is the main point here. It would be a little more complex if fetching articles concurrently, but still not a big deal.

Comment: You can first try the above solution by using e.g. `getSectionFlow().first()` - it will be similar to having a suspend function. Then, if it works, you can replace flow functions with suspend functions entirely, because they make more sense here.

Comment: BTW, this is just a digression, but why callbacks are parameterized here? Is it possible that e.g. `SectionCallback` is used to return something else than `List<MySection>`? It seems like you wanted to have just a single generic `Callback` interface, which is actually a good idea.

Comment: @broot thanks for the help it is resolved now

Comment: val sectionWithArticleList: MutableList<HCSectionWithArticle> = mutableListOf()
                val sectionList = getSection()
                    .map { hcSection ->
                        var articleList = getArticle(hcSection.id)
                        val hcSectionWithArticle = HCSectionWithArticle(
                            hcSection.id,
                            hcSection.title,
                            articleList
                        )
                        sectionWithArticleList.add(hcSectionWithArticle)
                    }

Comment: You don't have to create mutable list and add to it manually. `map()` already creates a list for you, you just need to return `HCSectionWithArticle` as the last expression in the lambda: `val sectionWithArticleList = getSection().map { ...; HCSectionWithArticle(...) }`.

Comment: voooo that's really nice it worked. Thanks a lot man really appreciated it.

Comment: And regarding, a single generic Callback interface yes that's my main goal. A lot of third-party libs are very old and they don't support coroutine. Hence I am currently converting all callback to a generic one